# Ограничение доступа по ip

Tags: ip, php

Привет, дорогие участники! У меня вопрос. Есть сайт, и я хочу, что бы он никому не был доступен, кроме этого ip 178.63.68.137 
Как ограничить для них доступ? И желательно, что бы выбивало надпись: "Наигрались?"
В хостинг панели нет возможности ограничить доступ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно через .htaccess сделать..

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 178.63.68.137
```

Надписи "Наигрался?", конечно, не будет в этом случае..

Можно еще так попробовать:

```
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR 178.63.68.137 REDIR="redir" 
RewriteCond %{REDIR} redir 
RewriteRule ^/$ /only_for_you.html
```

Если посетитель имеет IP-адрес 178.63.68.137, то ему будет открыта страница only_for_you.html.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] == "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"){
    exit("Message");
}
```

p.s. Минусанул за отсутствие попыток.